# EJS TreeGrid not working

Tags: html, ejs, treegrid

I was trying to work with EJS TreeGrid but I am not able to show the grid on browser.

I can't add the TreeGrid code in my HTML code properly. I have included library for GridE.js but it still doesn't show anything.

Can you help me with that, please ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html Lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> <title>MY APP</title>
  <script src="C:/Users/pathan/Desktop/ASP.net Tree grid/Grid/GridE.js?v  11_0"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <Grid>
    <Cfg id="Basic"/>
    <Panel Visible="1"/>
    <LeftCols>
      <C Width="200" Name="LEFT1"/>
    </LeftCols>
    <Cols>
      <C Name="DATA1"/>
      <C Name="DATA2"/>
    </Cols>
    <RightCols>
      <Toolbar Visible="1"/>
  </Grid>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have never used TreeGrid, but you forgot the end tag of your `<RightCols>` element...

Comment: @Badacadabra  Thanks But its still not working